# PHP detecting request type (GET, POST, PUT or DELETE) without using $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']

Tags: php

How can I find server request type `(GET, POST, PUT or DELETE)` without using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` from action page?

I am submitting page from `abc.php`
form action page is action page.

I need to print which method used

Comment: use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHO' . 'D']`, no but seriously can you explain why you can't use this global?

Comment: Why not use server var?

Comment: Can we know the reason?? Is it for something specific?

Comment: Yesterday I had an interview, interviewer asked almost same question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular if statements

```
if(!empty($_GET)) { 
    $request = (!empty($_POST)) ? 'both get and post' : 'get';
} else if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $request = 'post';        
}
//... You get the picture
```

**Edit:** I added a ternary within the get check to solve a problem that Gumbo noted in the comments. You can have both GET and POST vars available as you can POST data to a url with get params, i.e. /forms/addFileToCompany/?companyId=23

And now because I am a complete filth, the most horrible ternary you have ever seen! Note this is just for a bit of fun and I really do not recommend using it.

```
$request = (!empty($_GET)) 
    ? (!empty($_POST)) 
        ? 'both post and get' 
        : 'get'
    : (!empty($_POST))
        ? 'post'
        : (/* Keep it going for whatever */ );
```

Comment: What if there are URL and POST parameters?

Comment: @Gumbo touche. I updated the get clause with a statement checking the post to offer a third solution of 'both'.

Answer (score 1):

There's a tricky way and a not so smart way I believe. Is to check it manually like for example:

```
if( isset($_GET) ) $request_type = 'GET Method'; 
elseif( isset($_POST) ) $request_type = 'POST Method';
```

Comment: `$_GET` and `$_POST` are always set.